# PHPMailer and function mail()

Tags: email, php, smtp, localhost

Такая ситуация: с localhost сообщения прекрасно отправляются на любую почту через PHPMailer, но при попытке отправки с сайта выдаётся ошибка Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. Сейчас попробовал отправить с помощью функции mail() и всё сработало. Каковы могут быть причины SMTP connect() failed?

Comment: Опять двадцать пять. Код (нужную часть), оригинальный текст ошибки и конфигурацию в студию

Comment: Лол ну проблема в том, что нет подключения к смпт серверу или не удалось к нему подсоединиться по каким то причинам.